# (Solved) Plank : the Trash Docklet crashes Plank

Tags: pantheon-files, plank

When I try to empty the trash bin from the Trash Docklet in Plank (hit CTRL + Right Click on Plank to go the Plank Prefs and Docklets), it often crashes Plank (if not the whole desktop.)

And then, the Pref icon of Plank appears on the dock (blue anchor) and there's no way to get rid of it, but to close the session and come back.

A Plank problem or something in Pantheon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I updated Plank from the PPA. The newer version has a fix.

> Make window-manager aware that empty-trash dialog is part of plank
>   (LP: #1652653)

[Plank 0.11.4 “Eddy” Released! How to Install it via PPA](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/03/plank-0-11-4-eddy-released-how-to-install-it-via-ppa/)

Answer (score 2):

I found something similar using the stable version of Loki.  The unstable (daily) version works better - there is no persistent Plank item in the most recent version for example.

If the trash contains a large number (1000's) of files, then the context menu in plank can take several seconds to appear during which time Plank appears to freeze; presumably it is busy populating the context menu "restore" section with each file name.

Also in neither case did the "restore file" option on the context menu work.

I think this is mostly down to Plank - you can install a different filemanager - e.g. Thunar or Dolphin - and use Settings/Applications to set it as the default file browser.  The docklet launches the default filemanager.  I found the same behaviour using a different filemanager.

Comment: Well, I have used the Trash docklet in Unity and Cinnamon, no problem. In MATE, it was causing problems. So, not sure it's all Plank's fault.

Comment: It could be something in the underlying system or due to different library versions, but it did not seem to be specifically pantheon-files related.  Probably best to raise an issue against Plank initially since the visible effects you report are mostly in Plank.

Comment: Has anyone figured-out how to disable the trash files from appearing in Plank's context menu? It's a bit annoying having to wait for it to load whenever deleting a large number of files.